# LHM6642 - Open Loop

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to use LHM6642 as a comparator and I was wondering if it would work. The schematic that I have in mind is this one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkNKxN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the input I will inject a PWM signal (2V High, 0V Low). Using the a resistor voltage divider, I biased the inverting input of the OAmp to 1.2 V Aprox. The idea with this setup is to get the same square wave in the output but with the following voltage levels (12V High, 0V Low).

It seems to me this should work in theory. I have checked the datasheet of the Oamp but I haven't seen any information regarding if this Oamp can work in an open loop configuration.

Comment: You've left out the most important piece of information: what is the input square wave frequency (it's not 1kHz)?

Comment: Yes, 1 Khz. Thanks Kuba.

Comment: The LMH6642 is quite expensive compared to a jellybean comparator, is there a good reason to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work, however the op-amp will be saturated, so you'll have the overload recovery time to deal with.

Also there will be some loading of the input signal due to the -1.2V differential input voltage being in the range of two diode drops, especially at elevated temperature (Fig 54 in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6642.pdf)):

[image]

In general it's usually better not to use op-amps as comparators.

Answer (score 3):

The circuit equivalent to your circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgQkIe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The maximum absolute ratings of the op-amp state that the allowed differential voltage is 2.5V maximum, and the maximum input current is 10mA.

12V into 2k||18k is about 7mA, so assuming that V1 is no more than 12V above GND, you won't exceed the input current maximum - just barely, especially if the input can have spikes or other impulsive interference superimposed on it. Too close for comfort for me.

The resistive divider will allow the threshold voltage to shift around, and the maximum differential voltage rating won't likely be exceeded. Yet you're unlikely to get support from TI if you run into problems, since technically you're attempting to drive the part past its maximum differential input voltage.

This op-amp is not meant to be used with large differential inputs. To make it work passably, you may need to a fast, external BJT clamp like you'd see in multimeters, and add hysteresis.

Now, since you're using LMH6642 - a rather fast part - presumably the square wave is fast. 10MHz? Even at "only" 10MHz, you'll be pushing that poor op-amp to the limits - the output won't be directly usable as a logic signal, it'll have to go through a Schmitt trigger to speed it up. You might be surprised to see that this excellent op-amp may turn out to perform just slightly better than some jellybean comparator from 4 decades ago...

An actual comparator will have nice, sharp transitions on the output, will be able to easily drive a 500 Ohm load, won't have diodes shorting the inputs, and will be much faster than LMH6642 while likely consuming less power.

By using LMH6642 you're making everything harder than it needs to be.

The circuit as shown will likely oscillate like crazy, especially since you haven't shown any pictures of how you plan to put it together.